# iSeries network shares not working with new computer

Tags: ibm-midrange

I was able to access network shares on our iSeries server until I received a new computer. When I try to navigate to \server-name\share I am repeatedly prompted for my username or I will receive the error "Windows cannot access \server-name\share error code 0x800004005 unspecified error".

Both my old an new computer run Windows 7 64bit. I have changed the LAN Manager authentication level to "Send LM & NTLM - use NTLMv2 session security if negotiated" as detailed here:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1018525
I have also tried each Lan Manager option individually rebooting in between each one.

I have also walked through the instruction here:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1016520

Other users are able to access shares and I am able to access shares if I use a different computer.

I have cleared the credentials from Credential manager in the control panel. I have also tried clearing cache with "cwblogon servername /c"

I have tried changing my iseries password and setting my expiration to *NOMAX. I have also tried unchecking "use sharing wizard" from folder options.

I have been struggling with this for weeks and have rebooted dozens of times.

My old computer is still sitting on the shelf until I get this resolved so I can compare any settings.

Comment: Using WireShark I can see that in is using NTLM protocol. I'm also seeing this: Session Setup AndX Response Error: Access denied. just above I can see it is sending the correct username. although sometimes it looks like its using my windows username.